# Running asnyc function synchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, tus

I'm pretty new to JS. I'm using a third-party library that has an async callback. The problem is that I need to run through the function in its entirety before processing the next callback. I'm using an upload protocol called [tus.io](https://github.com/tus/tus-node-server/tree/main/packages/server#example-validate-metadata-when-an-upload-is-created) and need to process one upload at a time.

```
async onUploadCreate(req, res, uploadMetadata) {

    /* I need to check the metadata is valid by using an internal js file */
    //...

    /* Then I need to check the user is logged in by calling a third-party endpoint using axios*/
    //...

    /* Then I check the Mongo db for existing uploadId
    //...
        // if it's not there, create some entries in another db and add the uploadId to mongo
        //If it is there, get some IDs in mongo, which I append to another db
}
```

As you can see, I need to do a fair bit. I do this because in tus, there is no concept of an upload session; each file comes in an independent upload. I've been testing it by uploading one file at a time. When i use multiple files it's all over the place.

Is there a way I can achieve this in JavaScript? I know this could have a performance impact, so I'm open to suggestions on how else I could achieve this.

---

EDIT: as per the comments suggest, I've tried awaiting the functions that use axios and the mongo lib but this doesn't seem to make a difference. This is the complete function call:

```
async onUploadCreate(req, res, upload) {
        /* Check the metadata */
        const {ok, expected} = await common.validateMetadata(upload);
        if (!ok) {
            const body = `Expected "${expected}" in "Upload-Metadata" but received "${upload.metadata}"`;
            throw {status_code: 500, body};
        } else
        logger.info(`Metadata is ok!`);

        /* Check the user is logged in */
        const userAuthorised = await catalogue.getSession(upload.metadata.userSession);
        if (!userAuthorised) {
            const body = `User not authorised`;
            logger.info(`User with session id: "${upload.metadata.userSession}" not authed`);
            throw {status_code: 401, body};
        } else
            logger.info(`User with session id: "${upload.metadata.userSession}" is logged in`);

        /* Create the items in the catalogue and mongo db for tracking upload session*/
        // check the mongo db for existing uploadId
        const result =  await mongo.getUploadIdInDB(upload.metadata.uploadId);
        if (result == null) {
            logger.info(`Upload ID: "${upload.metadata.uploadId}" not found in mongodb`)
            // create a dataset in catalogue
            let dataset = await catalogue.createDataset(upload.metadata);
            // then create the datafiles in catalogue
            let datafile = await catalogue.createDatafile(dataset, upload.id, upload.size, upload.metadata);
            // then add the id in mongo
            await mongo.createUpload(upload.metadata, dataset, datafile)
        }
        else {
            logger.info(`Upload ID: "${upload.metadata.uploadId}" found in mongodb!`)
            // create a new datafile to go this dataset
            let datafile = await catalogue.createDatafile(result.datasetId[0], upload.id, upload.size, upload.metadata);
            // then add the id of the nre datafile to the upload entry in mongo
            await mongo.appendToUpload( result.datasetId, datafile)
        }
        logger.info(`Done processing upload file`)
        return res;
    },
```

For example the output I get is:

```
info: Metadata is ok! {"service":"upload-service"}
info: Metadata is ok! {"service":"upload-service"}
info: User with session id: "bb6190fb-369b-406e-8b64-b38bef644df6" is logged in {"service":"upload-service"}
info: User with session id: "bb6190fb-369b-406e-8b64-b38bef644df6" is logged in {"service":"upload-service"}
....
```

where id expect them to be interlaced

Comment: So use await `const response = await axios.get(...);` read the docs

Comment: No, it's impossible to run an asynchronous function synchronously. However, it's trivial to run multiple asynchronous steps *sequentially* - just `await` them.

Comment: Thanks, i've tried using await with no luck, however I haven't tried wrapping all the code in an await / async function. Maybe that would work?

Comment: I've tried wrapping the whole lot in an async function which I await but it doesn't make a difference

Comment: I think the problem is that I can’t stop the onUploadCreate function being called when it’s half way through dealing with a previous upload

Comment: The adapted code looks fine, but now the problem is in the part of the *calling* code that you haven't shared. Apparently you call `onUploadCreate` several times in a row, but also there you need to use `await` before such calls, which evidently you have not done.

Comment: `onUploadCreate` is provided as an option in the server init:
https://github.com/tus/tus-node-server/tree/main/packages/server#optionsonuploadcreate. see example here: https://github.com/tus/tus-node-server/tree/main/packages/server#example-validate-metadata-when-an-upload-is-created

Comment: "*When i use multiple files it's all over the place.*" - why exactly is that actually a problem? The entire appeal of asynchronous programming is that multiple users can interact with your server concurrently, without blocking each other. Still, in each call to `onUploadCreate` the code runs in the sequence you desire.

Comment: Because I need to create one postgresDB dataset entry per upload session (or grouping of datafiles), I have a mongoDB that stores the upload session id with the dataset id to track the upload session.

Comment: So, say the user uploads two files, the first datafile comes in and I look for the upload session id in mongo, it's not there, so I create it along with the postgres dataset entry. The second datafile file comes in, and I can look up the upload session id in Mongo and get the postgresDB dataset id, I can then relate the second datafile to this one dataset. The issue is the second call is firing before the first has a chance to make the mongo entry, so nothing is found.

Comment: Instead of querying, checking whether it's there, and conditionally inserting the item, use an [upsert](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/upsert/) that does this in a single operation

Answer (score 0):

Because the call is an async callback that I don't have access to, I can't `await` it. The answer was to dissolve the app’s responsibility to store any state, pushing any creation of database objects upstream to the front end or another service. This only meant the UI had to make 2 consecutive calls instead of one.

Comment: "Because the call is an async callback that I don't have access to, I can't await it". The normal solution to this is to use the lib's async API instead (assuming it's a reasonably modern library), [promisify](https://javascript.info/promisify) the callback so you _can_ await it, or dump the library if it doesn't have a promise-based interface and you can find a modern alternative.